# A question concerning the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(-1)>-1$, and $f(1)<1$. Show that $f$ has a fixed point.

So for every $y$ between $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ we can find an $x$ s.t. $-1<x<1$ and $f(x) = y$, but I'm not sure how to show one of these creates a fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the usual trick. Let $g(x) = x - f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, $g(x)$ is also continuous. Now $g(-1) < 0 < g(1)$. Applying the intermediate value theorem, there must be a $c \in (-1, 1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$. Hence, $g(c) = c - f(c) = 0$. We conclude...

Comment: Could you explain a little more, I am new to this

Comment: $g$ takes on all values between $g(-1)<0 $ and $g(1)>0$, hence there must be some point at which it equals zero.

Comment: Thanks copper.hat. @zb, I've updated my answer - let me know if this is clearer.

Comment: ohh wow. thanks